# Passing Pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, linked-list

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct LinkedList {
    int data;
    struct LinkedList * ll;
} ll;

void changehead(ll * h) {
    ll * new = malloc(sizeof(ll));

    h = new;

    printf("\n Func : %d", h);
}

int main() {
    ll * head = NULL;

    changehead(head);

    printf("\n Main : %d", head);
}
```

In this code the value of head didn't reflected inside of main, how do I pass head to the function so that it's value changes in main too.

Comment: Remember that arguments to functions are passed by value. Which means that the value used in the call will be copied into the functions local argument variable. Any changes, like assignment, will be lost when the life-time of the variable ends as the function returns. You need to emulate pass by reference by passing a pointer to the original variable, using the pointer-to operator `&`. The function then dereferences the pointer to modify the original variable.

Comment: You can change `void changehead(ll * h)` to `ll *changehead(void)` and then `return new;` From `main()`, `ll *head = changehead();`

Comment: On a couple of different notes, the correct `printf` format to print a `void *` pointer is `%p`. And you must cast the pointer to `void *`. Also please make it a habit to print a *trailing* newline. When `stdout` (which is where `printf` writes) is connected to a terminal, a newline will flush the output buffer and actually write the text. A leading newline will write the *previous* line, not the text actually in the `printf` call. Also, some terminals don't handle programs not ending its output with a newline very well.